# Reduce iPhone Ringer Volume Without Affecting Messagaging Alert Volume

Tags: iphone

I need to know how I can lower the volume on my phone ringer without lowering the volume for messaging alerts.  At night, I need Messaging to be LOUD, but I want my phone ringer to be barely audible (note: ringer still needs to emit some sound, not completely turned off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this isn't an option on a non-jailbroken device.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a silent (or very quiet) ringtone for phone calls and then have the normal sound play for messages. This site has a [walkthrough](http://richardkmiller.com/702/iphone-tip-use-a-silent-ringtone-to-screen-calls-in-your-sleep). You could also use the same trick to [silence calls from specific numbers](http://www.geekfori.com/iphone-silent-ringtone/).

Comment: This is a great tip, although the OP would need to change the ringtone every time it turns night, if they wanted to use the phone normally during the day.